# Best programming practice for dealing with an encapsulated collection?

Tags: c#, .net

In my class I have methods as such:

```
public List<int> IgnoredUsers;

public bool TryGet(int userId)
{
    return IgnoredUsers.Contains(userId);
}

public bool TryAdd(int userId)
{
    if (IgnoredUsers.Contains(userId))
    {
        return false;
    }

    IgnoredUsers.Add(userId);

    return true;
}

public bool TryRemove(int userId)
{
    return IgnoredUsers.Remove(userId);
}
```

The question is, should I be having all these methods or is it better programming practice to just return the dictionary and call the contains on the public field?

Comment: `bool TryAdd(int userId)` sounds a lot like you should be using a `HashSet<int>` instead

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you expand on the definition of your class and what purpose it's suppose to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `List<int>` with `ISet<int>` you would be able to perform all three operations directly on the `IgnoredUsers` collection, like this:

```
private readonly ISet<int> ignoredUsers = new HashSet<int>();
public bool Contains(int userId) => ignoredUsers.Contains(userId);
public bool Add(int userId) => ignoredUsers.Add(userId);
public bool Remove(int userId) => ignoredUsers.Remove(userId);
```

This approach is better than making `IgnoredUsers` available to the users of your class, because it lets your class decide which operations to expose.

**Note:** Prefix `Try...` in the names of your methods is somewhat misleading, because method signature does not follow .NET's `Try...` pattern, as in `TryGetValue` and `TryParse` methods. I renamed the methods for consistency with the corresponding collection methods.

Comment: I decided to go for this option, although I changed the return type of "Add" to a void and just stuck with List, it seemed to make more sense to me that way, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

These methods should be used if your collection was private.

And yes, `HashSet<int>` could be better.